# Private message to be saved as a draft

Tags: privatemsg

I want a Functionality in [Private message](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg) module drupal 7.x. That the message I am creating should be saved as a draft. how do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

There was a [patch for this for 6.x but it has not been updated for D7](https://www.drupal.org/node/258035).  If you want this feature now, you'll have to build it yourself.